# Relocated Home directory to exFAT partition => Skype freezes

Tags: skype, symlink

Do you have a fix for this particular scenario:

1) Two partitions boot drive, the second one formatted exFAT
2) Relocate Home directory to Partition2 using the default way:

System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Advanced Options -> Home directory

3) Install Skype
4) At first launch Skype will freeze / not connect / CMD + Q will also freeze Skype
5) Any other app except Skype works fine

I've tried installing Skype on two different systems (El Capitan & Mavericks) with Home directory relocated to another partition and the problem persist.

If you want to experience this and hopefully find a solution you can create a small partition of a few GBs and another OS user and move its Home directory to new partition created then try to install Skype.

UPDATE: I've just learned that the issue is related to how the second partition is formatted. Skype freezes while partition2 is formatted as ExFAT but if I format it as Mac OS Extended, Skype works fine.

I am ready to any kind of solution but is very very relevant for my that Desktop + Documents + Downloads folders to remain on partition2 formatted as ExFAT.

Thank you

Comment: Any thoughts about my issue will be appreciated. Maybe with the help of symlinks?

Comment: How did you relocate the home directory?

Comment: @Mark System Preferences -> Users -> Ctrl + Click on my username -> Advanced Options -> Home directory -> /Volume2/myUser/ -> Choose

Comment: then this looks like bugs in the crashing apps and you need to contact the developers

Comment: @Mark Skype customer support says this is OS X related issue and advice me to contact Apple Store. We all know this is just related to the fact that Skype is poor written and the app does not know to consult the table to find the current location of the Home directory and try to load it from /Volume1/Users/Admin/Library so I need a different approach

Comment: Hmm contact Apple Store re a program that does not comply to standards - isn't that a reason for Apple to remove it :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way of resolving this would be to create a partition to hold just your Home folder and then use `/etc/fstab` to mount the partition at `/Users/<username>`.

Otherwise a symbolic link between the new location of your Home and `/Users/<username>`is the best way to go. `ln -s <new_home> /Users/<username>`. Of course this replaces the current `/Users/<newname>`.

Frankly, I find this too much trouble and usually just trim my Home folder by moving such things as my iTunes library, which is easy and well supported by iTunes.

Comment: used sudo ln -s /Volumes/Data/Users/Admin /Users/Admin to create a symbolic link
/Volumes/Data = partition2
Admin = my username 
Skype still freeze during first launch